# Adding To State Without Overriding What Is Already In It (React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have multiple text inputs to create a 4 digit OTP entry. Once filled I obviously want them all to be combined to show me the final OTP.
Example:
2 4 3 6

although each digit is in a different text box, they need to be combined and then validated as (2436)

I created a state named `otpEntry: ''` and then added it all four text boxes. The issue is that the state is overridden each time. Instead I want to maintain the state and add the next digit to it. For instance, if the user enters (2) when he moves to the second box and enters (4) the state of `otpEntry` should be (24) not 4. I tried doing that the following way but it was unsuccessful.

```
                      <TextInput 
                  onChangeText={(otpEntry) => this.setState({otpEntry}), () => this.dig2.current.focus()} 
                  style={styles.otpInput}  
                  ref={this.dig1}
                  placeholder="X"
                  keyboardType="number-pad" 
                  />
                  <TextInput 
                  onChangeText={(otpEntry) => { this.setState(prevState => ({ otpEntry: prevState.otpEntry.concat(otpEntry) })) }, () => this.dig3.current.focus()} 
                  style={styles.otpInput}  
                  ref={this.dig2}
                  autoFocus = {this.state.otpdig2}
                  placeholder="X"
                  keyboardType="number-pad" 
                  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using components when you aren't displaying them. They'll still render and take extra processing power. Instead you can turn this into a function.

```
const [state, setState] = useState();

function append(input){
  let stateToChange = state;
  stateToChange = stateToChange.toString().append(input);
  setState(stateToChange);
}
```

If this function needs to return a number, you can use functions like parseInt() and parseFloat(). Here's a good example of what they'll do: https://gomakethings.com/converting-strings-to-numbers-with-vanilla-javascript/

Old answer before edit:

You should be able to do this.

```
<TextInput
  onChangeText={(text) => setState(text)}
  value={state}
/>
```

`onChangeText` returns a value of whatever the text box was changed to, then re-renders the component. Value sets the textbox on render.

Comment: I think the question was not clear enough, I just clarified it

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue using a hidden TextInput field that renders its input into a state. The state is then displayed using a single TextView. This made things very simple and straightforward

```
<TextInput style={{width: 0, height: 0}} keyboardType='numeric'autoFocus={true} onChangeText={(otpEntry) => this.setState({otpEntry})}/>
                  <Text style={styles.otpField}>{this.state.otpEntry}</Text>
```